How to classify a Facebook page as an App Page?
Some pages have the category of "App Page". It looks like this:

However, I can't figure out how to classify a page as an app page. For example, searching "App Page" under categories yields no results:

What do I need to do to setup my Facebook page as an app page?

These are created/setup via the Facebook Developer console at https://developers.facebook.com/, in App Settings > Advanced.


I tried this, but I didn't see the option to categorize the page as an "App Page".

@Foobar It's been a while since I've needed to do one, but my recollection is that doing this automatically sets that category as part of the process.
